# Existence of orthogonal transform that switches a linear subspace and a complement of it

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, reflection

Suppose $V$ is an $m$ dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$, $W$ is a complement of $V$, ($V$ and $W$ might not be orthogonal). Does there exist a orthogonal transform $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{2m \times 2m}$ s.t. $Q(V)=W, Q(W)=V$?

Intuitively I believe $Q$ does exist. For $m=1$, $V$ and $W$ are just lines through the origin, so we can take the angle bisector of $V,W$ and define $Q$ to be the mirror reflection across the angle bisector. But I don't know how to argue for $m>1$. It's difficult for me to define a high dimensional analogy of angle bisector of two linear subspaces with equal dimension.

Comment: What if you just take orthonormal bases $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_i\}$ for $V$ and $W$ respectively and switch $v_i$ with $w_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: Slightly more abstractly, let $T : V \to W$ be any isometric isomorphism and define $Q(v + w) = T(v) + T^{-1}(w), v \in V, w \in W$.

Comment: @TonyPizza I can see this works if $V$ is orthogonal to $W$. But if $V$ and $W$ are not orthogonal, I fail to see how $Q$ preserves length.

Comment: For $m=2$, let $u\in R^{2m}, u=x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 + y_1 w_1 + y_2 w_2$. Then $\langle u,u\rangle = x_1^2 + x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+2x_1y_1\langle v_1,w_1\rangle +2 x_1y_2\langle v_1,w_2\rangle +2x_2y_1\langle v_2,w_1\rangle +2x_2y_2\langle v_1,w_2\rangle $.

But $Qu=y_1 v_1 +y_2 v_2 + x_1 w_1 + x_2 w_2$, so $\langle Qu,Qu\rangle = x_1^2 + x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+2x_1y_1\langle v_1,w_1\rangle +2 x_2y_1\langle v_1,w_2\rangle +2x_1y_2\langle v_2,w_1\rangle +2x_2y_2\langle v_1,w_2\rangle$. Please notice the coefficients of $\langle v_1,w_2\rangle $ and $\langle v_2,w_1\rangle $ are different. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: As a result, $\langle Qu,Qu\rangle \neq \langle u,u\rangle $. So $Q$ is not orthogonal.

Comment: @cxh007 you are right. May be it's possible to find a basis for which it's isometric but that looks like harder way to prove if it's even true.

Comment: @cxh007: you said that $W$ was the complement of $V$ and I assumed you meant the orthogonal complement. Did you mean something else? (If you meant a not-necessarily-orthogonal complement, those aren't unique, so the terminology "its complement" is not appropriate; one should say "a complement, not necessarily orthogonal" or something.)

Comment: That's right. I mean a not-necessarily-orthogonal complement. I didn't realize my terminology is imprecise, thank you for pointing this out. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: I have edited the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For $m=2$ the idea of @Qiaochu Yuan works, but the isometric isomorphism $T$ has to be chosen appropriately. The transformation $Q(v+w)=Tv+T^{-1}w$ is an isometry iff $$\langle Tv,T^{-1}w\rangle =\langle v,w\rangle\quad (*)$$ Let $v_1,v_2$ and $u_1,u_2$ be orthonormal bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively. Define $T$ by
$$Tv_1=(\cos\alpha) u_1+(\sin\alpha) u_2=:w_1,\quad Tv_2=-(\sin\alpha )u_1+(\cos\alpha) u_2=:w_2$$ Then $w_1,w_2$ form an orthonormal basis of $W.$ Therefore the transformation $T$ extends to an isometric isomorphism from $V$ onto $W.$ The condition $(*)$ will be satisfied if $$\langle w_i,v_j\rangle=\langle Tv_i,T^{-1}w_j\rangle =\langle v_i,w_j\rangle\quad (**)$$ Clearly the latter holds for $i=j.$ Therefore it suffices to consider $i\neq j.$ WLOG we may assume that $i=1$ and $j=2.$ Then
$$\langle w_1,v_2\rangle=(\cos\alpha) \langle u_1,v_2\rangle+
(\sin\alpha) \langle u_2,v_2\rangle\\
\langle v_1,w_2\rangle=-(\sin\alpha) \langle v_1,u_1\rangle+
(\cos\alpha) \langle v_1,u_2\rangle$$ The condition $(**)$ is satisfied  if
$$\sin\alpha\,[\langle v_1,u_1\rangle+\langle u_2,v_2\rangle]=
  \cos\alpha\,[\langle v_1,u_2\rangle-\langle u_1,v_2\rangle]$$
The latter is satisfied for an angle $\alpha\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2].$

Comment: The geometric intuition is really clear. One can just rotate the randomly chosen orthonormal basis $\{u_i\}$ of $W$ to $\{w_i\}$ in order to make them kind of "mirror symmetric" to $\{v_i\}$, i.e., $\langle w_i,v_j \rangle = \langle w_j,v_i \rangle$.

Comment: I guess this can be generalized for $m>2$? The orthogonal transform $T:V\to W$ can be solved by forcing $\langle w_i,v_j \rangle = \langle w_j,v_i \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a $2m$-dimensional real inner product space such that $E = V\oplus W$ where $\dim(V)=\dim(W)=m$ but $V$ and $W$ are not assumed to be orthogonal.

*Claim*: There is a self-adjoint $Q\in \mathrm{O}(E)$ with $Q(V)=W$ and $Q(W)=V$. $Q$ is not unique unless $V\cap W^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

*Proof*: If $Q\in \mathrm{O}(E)$ is an isometry such that $Q(V)=W$, then its adjoint $Q^{\intercal}$ is its inverse, and $Q(V^{\perp})=W^{\perp}$. Moreover, the inner product restricts to give a pairing $b_V$ on $V$ and $b_W$ on $W$, but also a pairing
$$
b_{V,W}=\langle -,- \rangle \colon V\times W \to \mathbb R
$$
and if $v \in V, w\in W$ we must have $b_{V,W}(v,w) = \langle v, w\rangle = \langle Q(w), Q(v) \rangle = b_{V,W}(Q(w),Q(v))$. In particular since the left-radical of $b_{V,W}$ is $V\cap W^{\perp}$ while the right-radical is $V^{\perp}\cap W$ the since $Q(V)=W$ and $Q$ is an isometry,  $Q(V\cap W^{\perp}) = W\cap V^{\perp}$. Since $b_V$ is an inner product on $V$, it follows that $V = (V\cap W^{\perp}) \oplus (V\cap W^{\perp})^{\perp_V}$, where $(-)^{\perp_V}$ denotes the subspace of vectors in $V$ orthogonal to $(-)$, that is $(-)^{\perp_V} = (-)^{\perp} \cap V$. Thus we obtain
$$
V = (V\cap W^{\perp}) \oplus (V\cap(W+V^{\perp})),
$$
an orthogonal direct sum. Similarly, we find that $W$ decomposes as the orthogonal direct sum $(W\cap V^{\perp})\oplus (W\cap(V+W^{\perp}))$. The pairing $b_{V,W}$ restricts to a nondegenerate pairing between $V\cap (W+V^{\perp})$ and $W\cap (V+W^{\perp})$, so that we have
$$
E = (V\cap W^{\perp})\oplus \left(V\cap(W+V^{\perp}) \oplus (W\cap (V+W^{\perp})\right) \oplus (V^{\perp}\cap W)
$$
an orthogonal direct sum decomposition of $E$ into $3$ subspaces, the second of which has two summands which are nondegenerately paired by the inner product.

Recall that a nondegenerate bilinear pairing $b\colon U_1\times U_2\to \mathbb R$ on two finite-dimensional vector spaces $U_1$ and $U_2$ induces isomorphisms $\theta_1\colon U_1\to U_2^*$ and $\theta_2\colon U_2 \to U_1^*$ (where $U_1$ and $U_2$ may or may not be distinct) defined by $\theta_1(u_1)(u_2) = b(u_1,u_2)$.

To construct $Q$, one may choose any isometry $q\colon (V\cap W^{\perp}) \to (W\cap V^{\perp})$. On the other hand, the bilinear pairings $b_V, b_W,b_{V,W}$ give maps $\theta_V\colon V\to V^*, \theta_W \colon W\to W^*$ and $\theta_{V,W}\colon V \to W^*$, which restrict to give the following diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V\cap (W+V^{\perp}) @>{\theta_{V,W}}>> (W\cap (V+W^{\perp}))^* \\
@V{\theta_{V}}VV @A{\theta_{W}}AA \\
(V\cap (W+V^{\perp})^* @<{\theta_{W,V}}<< (W\cap(V+W^{\perp}))
\end{CD}
$$
Thus we obtain a canonical isometry $c:=\theta_W^{-1}\circ \theta_{V,W}\colon V\cap (V^{\perp}+W)\to W\cap (W^{\perp}+V)$.
on $V\cap (W+V^{\perp})$, and its adjoint $c^{\intercal}\colon \theta_{W,V}\circ\theta_V^{-1}\colon W\cap (W^{\perp}+V) \to V\cap(V^{\perp}+W)$ is its inverse. Cashing out what this means from the definitions is that the condition that
$$
\langle v,w\rangle = \langle c^\intercal(w),c(v)\rangle \quad \forall v\in V, w\in W
$$
in fact uniquely specifies what $c^{\intercal}(w)$ and $c(v)$ have to be!

Combining with $q$ we obtain the map $Q$ given by $(q\oplus c)\oplus (q^{\intercal}\oplus c^{\intercal})$, an isometry interchanging $V$ and $W$. The uniqueness assertion is just the statement that $c$ is canonical.